Why do I measure different resistances in the same wire at different current levels?
I've been doing some testing recently on the resistances of various pieces of aluminum for some applications. I've been measuring the resistances of these pieces by passing a constant current through the piece and measuring the voltage across the part. I also am taking temperature measurements of these parts during this process.
What I've found is that the measured resistance across the part is proportional to the temperature of the piece (this is expected of course) but also to the current that is applied. If I were to plot the measured resistance vs. temperature of the part for different currents applied I get plots such as the example below:

What is a reasonable explanation for this? My initial assumption is that the core temperature of the part is higher than the surface temperature I am measuring, however these parts are <2mm in thickness so I would expect this effect to be minimal.
EDIT: Lots of requests for more information on the test setup and raw data.
For my current generation and measurements I'm using a battery cycler system (Arbin LBT) capable of generating up to 500A. This also performs the voltage measurement using 4-terminal sensing. The resistance is calculated by the measured voltage and current at each data point.
Temperature measurement is performed with 3 Type T thermocouples spaced across the sample (temperature reported in this data is the average of these 3 measurements).
Connections:

Raw Data Plot:

Hardware Specifications:


ambient temperature, or temperature of the conductor?

The temperature here is temperature of the conductor. Specifically the average of three measurements along the conductor. Conductor is a rectangular element about 20mm*65mm and <2mm thick.

How are you measuring the temperature? Direct contact or IR?

Your graph looks a bit dry-lab-y. Straight noise-free lines? How many temperature points did you take? Are you attempting a dynamic measurement as the part self-heats? What temperature measurement method is being used and what are the dead times and the time constant(s), if it matters? The exact same difference between 200&300 vs. 300&400 is either likely important (given square law loss) or perhaps suspicious. If you've simplified the data for us you may have simplified away useful information. Especially if you have data with a time component.

How are you generating and measuring these huge currents?

Temperature is being measured with Type T thermocouples directly on the sample. This graph is dry lab-y, I made an example graph to highlight the trend in the data, not the exact graph from my results.Currents are being generated with an Arbin battery tester equipment.

where are your 4 point probes located? Extra resistance as f(current) suggests extra length is being included. Show a photo of your experimental setup showing where the current and voltage probes are.

Not "proportional", but "a function of". Evidently, with 4x as much current, the resistance is only somewhere on the order of 20% higher, not 4x. My guess is that you're running into problems due to the non-zero internal resistance of your meter. Putting hundreds of amps through pieces of metal is well into "don't try this at home" territory after all. Also noteworthy: this amount of current is going to heat up the metal, over time...

By "directly on the sample" do you (hopefully) mean a ribbon thermocouple with something like Kapton electrical insulation? Without electrical insulation .. well a 1°C error is of the order of 40uV, and would be proportional to current. Thermal insulation (aside from the sample itself, ofc), would also be a good idea to keep the lead temperatures from affecting the reading.

@MatthewCollier Can you show us your actual results? How are you measuring that the "constant" current is actually constant?

@SpehroPefhany Yes that's exactly the setup for the thermocouples.

I think there's a lot of room for errors in that setup. Assuming you're using self-heating for the temperature change, there will be a delta between measured and actual temperature and DUT temperature roughly proportional to the dT/dt. The insulated bead is is a poor way to measure surface temperature compared to ribbon T/C or other means. The Kelvin sense connections are dubious as well. The alligators (probably steel) have multiple possible points of contact and large uncertainty of the distance between them. Calculate the time delta for the temperature differences you are seeing.

I would expect the T/C to have a time constant in the seconds. There's also heat loss down the thermally conductive leads vs. the insulated and point-contact bead. It's not easy to accurately measure surface temperature of a part like that. IR is one way but you would have to paint the metal  to get the emissivity under control and have a sensor that could resolve a small spot.

I would want to see the measurement uncertainty and I would want to be sure that a good 4-point measurement is being performed before I even started to think about explaining the result.

Agree with this, though it may be better as a comment.  Also, due to the surface oxidation layer on Al, the method of making contact to the conductor may impact the measurement.

The measurements are being performed with 4-point measurements. I have my current cables bolted through the aluminum and the sense wires attached to the aluminum itself, inside the current connections. I’ll have to double check the last calibration on this equipment but the voltage should be well within a reasonable tolerance (even at the 100A level I’m seeing 6-7mV)
I’ve run this test with multiple Al alloys (and even some copper) and find similar trends.
John to your point I haven’t adjusted the connections between these measurements, would that still be of concern?

@MatthewCollier I don't suppose it would be an issue if you haven't adjusted the connections, but I don't know for sure.  Just brainstorming, but another possibility could be that the magnetic field around the conductor may be interfering with your measurement.  It's not AC, so not inducing currents, but maybe affecting the instruments in some other way.

Based on previous comments and answers, these results are unexpected.  I suspect something in your test set-up or experimental method is causing this. To assist you further, I suggest you provide further information on your experimental set-up, such as a list of equipment, and photos.  Details that would be helpful are:

Equipment that generates the test current (make, model), and waveform of same (is it AC, DC, or DC + some ripple), and the means of connecting this current to the sample.
Equipment that measures the voltage drop across the test sample, how it is co-located with all the other equipment, and the means of connection to the sample.
Equipment that measures the temperature of the sample.
Do you have the raw data of the voltage & current measurement from which the resistance was calculated?

Edit: I just noticed this in a new comment to one of the other answers here:

and the sense wires attached to the aluminium itself, inside the current connections.

So from this, is it the case that your set-up has the standard four-point connection, as illustrated by the images below?

Link for above image:
https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Color-online-Four-point-probe-measurements-of-semiconductor-resistance-a-The-outer_fig6_276506214

Link for above image:
https://mgchemicals.com/knowledgebase/white-papers/4-point-probe/
Suggested Activity
I suggest testing the integrity of your experimental setup up and measurement system.  Here are some activities for that, posed as "questions":
Q1. What is the voltage reading when the two voltage-sense wires (or probe tips) are touching together, are physically located close to where they normally are located during the experiment, but are not touching the sample (a gap of about 10mm), under each of the conditions:
(a) All other powered equipment close to the experiment is turned off, leaving only the minimum equipment powered required for the voltage measurement.
(b) Energise all equipment one at a time, observing the voltage reading each time.  Note any step that causes the voltage reading to change.
(c) Once all equipment is energied, set up sample current to be zero, and again note the reading of the voltage measurement device.
(d) Gradually increase the current in the sample from zero up to the maximum used in the experiment.
Q2. Repeat the test of Q1, this time the voltage sense wires are still touching each other, but are both moved to be also touching the sample, at a point midway between the two heavy current connections.
Q3. Repeat test of Q2, this time separate the two sense wires by a very small distance (less than 5% of the normal separation distance) while both are still touching the sample.  Again, start current at zero, and gradually increase up to maximum.
Q4. Repeat test of Q3, this time move the two voltage sense probes from the middle position of the sample, and place them both closer to one, then the other, heavy current connection.
Q5. What happens when you reverse the connections of these wires at the point where they connect into the voltage measurement device at each step of Q2 above?
Of course, we would expect the answer to all of these "questions" will be very close to zero (to within the uncertainty of the measurement system).  If they are not all zero, then this may indicate a problem with the measurement system.

If we take the values at 30°C and plot the voltage vs. current:

The relationship is linear, as would be expected if the resistance is constant, but intercept is not at 0 mV. The offset voltage causes lower than real resistance measured at lower current levels.
You could try replotting the measurements but adding 2.2 mV to measured voltages.
One possible cause of voltage offset could be thermoelectric effects, though this seems somewhat unlikely if both cables are of same material.
In any case, reversing the voltage sense connections and repeating measurements could shed some light on the issue.


Figure 1.
AESA Caortaillod (chosen at random) gives the temperature coefficient of resistivity of aluminium as 0.403 %/°C.
Taking points 1 (77.5 μΩ) and 2 (97.5 μΩ) in Figure 1, we have

ΔT = 40°C.
ΔR = (97.5 - 77.5) / 77.5 = 25.8%

Using the tempco figure we're expecting,

ΔR = ΔT × 0.403 = 40 × 0.403 = 16.1%.

You're getting 50% more than the expected change so your concerns are justified.
I have no idea why!

I agree with the discrepancy, but the calculation seems to have an error: second equation should also have delta-T of 40°C, giving 16% expected change.

@jpa, thank you for the feedback. I was originally going to use 50° and forgot between marking the graph and doing the calculation. Well, I should get marks for correct method at least - even if the calculation was wrong!

Such measurements must be done with AC. You'll get rid of thermoelectic effects that way. What you're seeing is most likely thermoelectric.

I'm using a battery cycler system

That's the problem.
You should be using an AC microohmmeter. It won't need 500A to measure 50μΩ. 1A will be plenty. In fact, you can probably build one yourself and it will work spectacularly compared to the battery cycler. The current can be measured with a transformer, since there's no DC component to worry about. That will be fairly stable with temperature. If you can do it with an air core - even better.
To measure temperature you can use thermocouples or semiconductor junction (PTAT) sensor, or a high tempco crystal thermally bonded to the wire. Crystal resonators are splendid temperature sensors, with μK sensitivity - and all you need for readout is an oscillator circuit and a frequency meter!

My first comment would be regarding your poor measurement configuration that will surely not give very accurate results.

The voltage taps (I guess these are the crocodile clamps) position is not well defined as the clamp is quite large as compared to sample length. You should hence use point contact so you can define the sample length more precisely
The voltage is the difference in electrical potentials. These depend on current flow lines that, in you design, are probably not homogeneous through the sample cross-section due to the different values of total path resistance. To overcome this, we suggest to have a distance between current injection points and voltage taps of at least 3 times the sample width.

But coming back to your questions:
Regarding the temperature behaviour. 0.403%/°C s the value for pure aluminium given in IEC standards for power cable conductors. It represents a linear extrapolation of the temperature curve around 20°C. This value might change a bit with alloying.
The temperature correction is given by the following formula
RTn=R(1+a(Tn-20°C))/(1+a(T-20°C)
Where
RTn     = Resistance at reference temperature
R   = Resistance at test temperature
a   = Material temperature coefficient
Tn  = Reference temperature
T   = Temperature of conductor during test
So calculating the temperature behaviour of a aluminium resistor with 73microOhm at 25°C gives you a value of approx. 86microOhm at 70°C which corresponds reasonnably to the upper curve of your graph. So this looks fine.
Regarding the offset: as mentionned EMF can be accounted for by measuring the same system with forward reverse polarity and taking the mean value of both measurements.
You can also measure the system without current. That should give you the offset you need to correct your measurements.
Using AC measurement is also a possibility, however this will introduced issues related to skin effect and electromagnetic fields if the dimensions of your system is not much smaller than the penetration depth. So I would avoid this solution in your case if you plan to use 50 Hz (aluminum penetration depth is about 12.3 mm) and a non-cylindrical sample (current accumulation in edges)
